# Populate dropdown using an Angular model (ng-model)

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, angularjs, angular-ui

I have an Angular model `ng-model="car"` I am trying to create a dropdown list, and would like the list items to be populated from objects in the model.  I am trying to do this all in the HTML (since it is Angular).
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a form input: http://angular-ui.github.com/#/directives-select2
If you want a dropmenu: http://angular-ui.github.com/bootstrap/#/dropdownToggle

Checkout the dropmenu source code too to get an idea of how to go about doing it if you rather code up your own solution.

Essentially AngularJS makes it so easy that the ONLY thing you really need to do is toggle the visibility of a DOM element and use some fancy css.

Checkout this example of using pure AngularJS + AngularUI (when necessary) alongside Bootstrap's CSS to create dropmenus (and other widgets) http://plnkr.co/edit/gist:4464334?p=preview